# Can someone please explain why document["write"] works?

Tags: javascript

I was helping to de-obfuscate a javascript snippet today, and was surprised to find this:

```
document["write"]('obfuscated code here');
```

The word "write" was also obfuscated, making it slightly harder to understand the code's intent.

I've never seen document treated as an array before, and I'm curious how/why this works.  Are there other functions that can be called in a similar manner?

Comment: [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

Comment: Bracket notation and dot notation can both be used and do the same thing when accessing an object with keys, and `document` is an object where `write` is a property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document` is a Javascript object (not an array). Object fields can be accessed by dot (`parent.child`) or subscript (`parent['child']`) syntax.

You can try it yourself:

```
var myObject = {
  field: 'hello!'
}

console.log(myObject['field']);
console.log(myObject.field);
```

The subscript syntax is useful when you have a field name that is not a valid Javascript identifier:

```
var myObject = {
  'my-field': 'hello!'
}

console.log(myObject['my-field']);     // Works as expected
console.log(myObject.my-field);        // ReferenceError
console.log(myObject.'my-field');      // SyntaxError
```

See the [MDN docs on property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators).

Answer (score 2):

Because you can access object keys as `['key']` as well as `.key`. "Classes" in javascript are just objects.

Consider the following:

```
var foo = {
    bar: function() {
        alert('We are here!');
    }
};

foo.bar(); //The bar key of the object accessed using .key
foo['bar'](); //The bar key of the object accessed using ['key']
```

Answer (score 2):

Because document is an object in javascript, a DOM object.
And in javascript its possible to access properties by using either object.property or object['property']

So you can write it as

```
document.write(...);
```

OR

```
document['write'](...);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of notation: dot (`.`) and array(`[]`) when dealing with objects. Both will access the property named after the dot or in the index

So if you have something like

```
var obj = {
  someproperty:"something",
  somefunction:function(){}
};
```

Both `obj.someproperty` and `obj["someproperty"]` reference the object's property with that name.

This of course will also work on arrays, except you cannot use dot notation to access the elements, as arrays are just objects.

```
var arr = [2,1,3];
console.log(arr[1])
arr["sort"]();
console.log(arr)
```

However you cannot access the array's elements through dot notation

```
arr.1
```

will throw an error